# How to programmatically trigger an Update message in CRM 4.0?

Tags: .net, plugins, dynamics-crm-4

I wrote a plugin that deals with Create, Update, Delete messages on a custom entity to sync data to another system. Now the problem is that I need to execute the plugin code that handles the Update message when other related entities are updated (basically would cause a data refresh on the other system).

I was thinking of creating another plugin (or in the same one I already wrote) and register it to Update messages of all the other entities involved and trigger an update.
Would this be as simple as Execute(ing) an UpdateRequest with let's say a new value for a bogus attribute when the updates on the related entities are triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing a bogus attribute would work (assuming the update step ISN'T a pre-validation step). But if you're creating another plugin, you could also call your sync code directly, no?